# RoR ActiveResource nested resources : Difference between 3.2.1 and 3.0.7

Tags: ruby-on-rails, jruby, activeresource

I have two simple models, clown.rb and funny_hat.rb.

ARes 3.0.7

```
clown = Clown.new({:funnyHats => [{ :id => "123" },{ :id => "456" }]})
p clown
#<Clown:0x3091b721 @prefix_options={},
@attributes={"funnyHats"=>[#<FunnyHat:0x7fd8623b @prefix_options={}, @attributes={"id"=>"123"}>, #<FunnyHat:0x3f18dc75 @prefix_options={}, @attributes={"id"=>"456"}>]}>
```

ARes 3.2.1

```
clown = Clown.new({:funnyHats => [{ :id => "123" },{ :id => "456" }]})
p clown
#<Clown:0x1f38b39c @prefix_options={}, @persisted=false, 
@attributes={"funnyHats"=>[#<Clown::FunnyHat:0xbd8632b @prefix_options={}, @persisted=false, @attributes={"id"=>"123"}>, #<Clown::FunnyHat:0x44adf91a @prefix_options={}, @persisted=false, @attributes={"id"=>"456"}>]}>
```

There appears to be a difference to nested resources with ARes 3.2.1 from ARes 3.0.7. Notice how in ARes 3.2.1 output, the "Clown::FunnyHat" nodes. I recall this occurring with ARes 3.0.7 when there was no FunnyHat.rb model declared.

**Question:** Is this a problem that can be worked around?

**Update**

If I do the following in ARes 3.2.1, I get a different result.

```
funny_hat = FunnyHat.new()
clown = Clown.new({:funnyHats => [{ :id => "123" },{ :id => "456" }]})
p clown
#<Clown:0x506d043e @prefix_options={}, @persisted=false, 
@attributes={"funnyHats"=>[#<FunnyHat:0x70596c33 @prefix_options={}, @persisted=false, @attributes={"id"=>"123"}>, #<FunnyHat:0x381ba0c6 @prefix_options={}, @persisted=false, @attributes={"id"=>"456"}>]}>
```

The reason this matters is because if the node is "Clown::FunnyHat", it doesn't map to the "FunnyHat" model, and therefore the instances do not have any of the instance methods or attributes of a "FunnyHat" object.

**Another Interim Hack**

Put the following in some initializer step or before_filter

```
Dir.glob("#{Rails.root}/app/models/*.rb").sort.each { |file| require_dependency file }
```

Thanks https://github.com/rails/rails/issues/5148

I'm beginning to think that ActiveResource 3.2.1 is a major regression from ActiveResource 3.0.7.